# Need approximating formulas for Arctan(x) , i know the taylor series but other than that?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

And can deviate for large values , just need some approximations

Comment: If you can explain what is inadequate about Taylor series it would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple trick to boost the convergence: For *all* $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have

$$ \arctan x = 2\arctan \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}\right) = 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}\right)^{2n+1}. $$

Of course you can mix this with other strategies to get even better convergence.

---

Alternatively, here is an efficient series expansion found by Euler:

$$ \arctan x = \frac{x}{x^2+1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{2k}{2k+1} \frac{x^2}{x^2+1} \right) $$

Since there is no sign change, this may be better suited for controlling numerical error.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\arctan(x) = \pi/2 - \arctan(1/x)$ for $x > 0$.
Thus the asymptotic series for large (positive) $x$ is 
$$ \arctan(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{3x^3} - \frac{1}{5 x^5} + \ldots$$
converging for $x \ge 1$.

On the other hand, if you want good approximating polynomials on a given interval 
you might try a Chebyshev series.  Or for optimal uniform approximations, use the Remez algorithm.  For example, the best degree-$7$ uniform approximation of $\arctan(x)$ on the interval $[-2,2]$ is (approximately)
$$ 0.9823206884 x- 0.2449205924 x^3+0.05605534355 x^5-0.005430801955 x^7$$
with maximum absolute error approximately $0.003243821677$ on this interval.